# How to replace string in CSV::Table without destructive method

Tags: ruby

I want to replace string in `CSV::Table`.
I could replace the string by using `gsub!` like this:

```
csv = CSV.table(@csv_file)
csv[:tag].each do |tag|
  tag.gsub!('Replace1','Replace2')
  tag.gsub!('Replace3','Replace4')
end
```

But I prefer to use `gsub` with method chain

```
csv[:tag].each do |tag|
  tag = tag.gsub('Replace1','Replace2').
            gsub('Replace3','Replace4')
end
```

Unfortunately it doesn't change the csv[:tag] strings.
How can I replace string in CSV::Table class without using `gsub!`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gsub!` returns `self`, so you can do the same thing:

```
tag.gsub!('Replace1','Replace2').
    gsub!('Replace3','Replace4')
```

If you want to replace a string with a string you already calculated, you can use `String#replace`:

```
new_tag = tag.gsub('Replace1','Replace2').
              gsub('Replace3','Replace4')
tag.replace(new_tag)
```

Comment: probably the assignment is unneccesary

Comment: `gsub!` return `self` only when there is match, so I'll use `replace` method. Thanks!